# Cannot mock WSRequest.post() using scalamock

Tags: scala, playframework, scalamock, play-ws

I am writing unit tests for Play application using Scalamock and Scalatest.

My original code looks like:

```
// Here ws is an injected WSClient
val req = Json.toJson(someRequestObject)
val resp: Future[WSResponse] = ws.url(remoteURL).post(Json.toJson(req))
```

In a part I have to mock external calls to a web service, which I am trying to do using scalamock:

```
ws = stub[WSClient]
wsReq = stub[WSRequest]
wsResp = stub[WSResponse]

ws.url _ when(*) returns wsReq
wsReq.withRequestTimeout _ when(*) returns wsReq
(wsReq.post (_: java.io.File)).when(*) returns Future(wsResp)
```

I am successfully able to mock post requests using a file, but I cannot mock post requests using JSON.

I tried putting stub function references separately like:

```
val f: StubFunction1[java.io.File, Future[WSResponse]] = wsReq.post (_: java.io.File)

val j: StubFunction1[JsValue, Future[WSResponse]] = wsReq.post(_: JsValue)
```

I get the compile error for second line: `Unable to resolve overloaded method post`

What am I missing here? Why cannot I mock one overloaded method but not the other one?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/leanovate/play-mockws ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`play.api.libs.ws.WSRequest` has two `post` methods (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WSRequest), taking:

1. `File`
2. `T` (where `T` has an implicit bounds on `Writeable`)

The compiler is failing because you are trying to calling `post` with a single parameter, which only matches version 1. However, `JsValue` cannot be substituted with `File`.

You actually want to call the 2nd version, but this is a curried method that takes two sets of parameters (albeit the 2nd are implicit). Therefore you need to explicitly provide the mock value that you expect for the implicit, i.e.

`val j: StubFunction1[JsValue, Future[WSResponse]] = wsReq.post(_: JsValue)(implicitly[Writeable[JsValue]])`

Therefore a working solution would be:

`(wsReq.post(_)(_)).when(*) returns Future(wsResp)`

*Old answer:*

`WSRequest` provides 4 overloads of `post` method (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.8/api/java/play/libs/ws/WSRequest.html), taking:

1. `String`
2. `JsonNode`
3. `InputStream`
4. `File`

You can mock with a `File` because it matches overload 4, but `JsValue` does not match (this is part of the Play JSON model, whereas `JsonNode` is part of the Jackson JSON model). If you convert to a `String` or `JsonNode`, then it will resolve the correct overload and compile.

Comment: Thanks Woodz. The question is quite specific to Scala. It doesn't have an overloaded method for JsonNode. The supposed overrride here is:

`def post[T](body: T)(implicit arg0: BodyWritable[T]): Future[Response]`

Comment: Thanks @Xolve - I missed that you were using the Scala Play API

Comment: Thanks @J0HN. You answer provided me with what I needed for :)

Though the actual solution is a little different that what it should be.
1. Explicit types are needed.
2. Two wildcards parameters are required. It would look like:

`(wsReq.post(_: JsValue)(_: BodyWritable[JsValue])) when(*, *) returns Future(wsResp)`

Comment: Also, how did you arrive at that there is an implicit involved? In the declaration of post method, there is no such thing:

`override def post[T: BodyWritable](body: T): Future[Response]`

Comment: @Xolve a context bound in Scala is syntactic sugar for an implicit parameter of that type specialised on the generic type. For example, `post[T : BodyWriteable]` is the same as `post[T](implicit evidence$0: BodyWriteable[T])` (https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html)

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that your `WSRequest` is actually a `play.libs.ws.WSRequest` which is part of the Java API, instead you should use `play.api.libs.ws.WSRequest` which is the Scala API.

The method [`WSRequest.post`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WSRequest@post[T](body:T)(implicitevidence$2:play.api.libs.ws.BodyWritable[T]):scala.concurrent.Future[WSRequest.this.Response]) exists and [`BodyWritable[JsValue]`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WSBodyWritables@writeableOf_JsValue:play.api.libs.ws.BodyWritable[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]) is implicitly provided by `WSBodyWritables` in the Scala API but not in the Java API.

Another cause could be that your `JsValue` is not a `play.api.libs.json.JsValue` but something else (e.g. `spray.json.JsValue`).

Answer (score 1):

I'll quote an example where I have successfully achieved what you are trying to do, the main difference is that I used `mock` instead of `stub`.

The important part is:

```
val ws = mock[WSClient]
val responseBody = "{...}"
...
"availableBooks" should {
  "retrieve available books" in {
    val expectedBooks = "BTC_DASH ETH_DASH USDT_LTC BNB_LTC".split(" ").map(Book.fromString).map(_.get).toList

    val request = mock[WSRequest]
    val response = mock[WSResponse]
    val json = Json.parse(responseBody)

    when(ws.url(anyString)).thenReturn(request)
    when(response.status).thenReturn(200)
    when(response.json).thenReturn(json)
    when(request.get()).thenReturn(Future.successful(response))

    whenReady(service.availableBooks()) { books =>
      books.size mustEqual expectedBooks.size

      books.sortBy(_.string) mustEqual expectedBooks.sortBy(_.string)
    }
  }
}
```

An you could see the complete test at: [BinanceServiceSpec](https://github.com/AlexITC/crypto-coin-alerts/blob/master/alerts-server/test/com/alexitc/coinalerts/services/external/BinanceServiceSpec.scala)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should work fine, if you mock a response that is JsValue.

```
when(wsReq.post(Json.parse("""{...json request...}"""))).thenReturn(Future(wsResp))
```

Here `Json.parse` returns `JsValue`. Yo should pass the json string that you expect in the request body.